# Read from XML getting undesired outcome

Tags: c#, xml

I just need to read from this simple XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<NewsUpdate>
     <TextNews>
         currentNews.txt
     </TextNews>
     <VideoNews>
         Live Avatar Meet Sean.mp4
     </VideoNews>
</NewsUpdate>
```

this is my code to read text from elements "TextNews" and "VideoNews"

```
xmlDoc = XDocument.Load("Assets/Resources/InovationNewsUpdate.xml");
root = xmlDoc.Root
IEnumerable<XElement> textElement =
        from el in xmlDoc.Descendants("TextNews")
        select el;
    foreach (XElement el in textElement)
    {
        //XMLData is a class to handle storing of elements data
        textNews.Add(new XMLData(el.ToString()));
    }

IEnumerable<XElement> videoElement =
        from el in xmlDoc.Descendants("VideoNews")
        select el;
    foreach (XElement el in videoElement)
        videoNews.Add(new XMLData(el.ToString()));
```

this is the code for XMLData

```
public class XMLData{

    public string charText;

    public XMLData (string character)
    {
        charText = character;
    }
}
```

when i read the content from the TextNews, the values inside wasn't as what i desired

```
foreach (XMLData dataIn in textNews)
{
    loadFile = dataIn.charText;

    Debug.Log("File :" + loadFile);
}
```

results:

```
File: <TextNews>   currentNews.txt
```

answer which i supposed to get is File:currentNews.txt i really don't understand why< TextNews > appear in the result

pls help

Comment: Are you planning to make future changes to your `XMLData` class? As it is now, it looks like just a very convoluted approach to passing around a `string` value.

Answer (score 1):

`el.ToString()` returns the string representation of an element (including its tags). To get the element's value, use:

```
textNews.Add(new XMLData((string)el));
```

Answer (score 1):

instead of `el.ToString()` you have to use `el.Value`. 
I hope this can help you.